# Java String replace method with lambda funcion

Tags: java, string, replace

I want do String replace without specifying replacement String as literal String.

```java
Supplier<String> random = () -> anyExpensiveProcess();
String text = "abcd xyz";
text = text.replace("xyz", random);
```

If "xyz" exists, then call `random` to generate replacement String.

Comment: what about `text.replace("xyz", random.get());`? That simply invokes the `Supplier`. `replace` does not check if the "xyz" exists though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `String.replace()` and `String.replaceAll()` functions do not accept a lambda but according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)), "*an invocation of this method of the form `str.replaceAll(regex, repl)` yields exactly the same result as the expression*:

```
Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)
```

Therefore, I suggest you try:

```
Pattern.compile("xyz").matcher(text).replaceFirst(mr -> random.get());
```

Edit: Matcher has `replaceFirst` ond `replaceAll`, not `replace()`.  Both take a `Function<MatchResult,String> replacer`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make your own method for that:

```
public String replaceIfFound(String subject, String target, Supplier<String> replacement) {
    if(!subject.contains(target)) {
      return subject;
    }
    return subject.replace(target, replacement.get())
}
```

This way the `Supplier` will only be invoked if the subject contains the String you're looking for.